# I can't write to my sd card

Tags: sd-card

Some unknown file types appeared with weird name but significant size(one is 1.8gb), also can't delete it. After i reboot my phone, they disappear along with some other files like my photos and videos but i am able to write to my sd card for some days and again the same problem repeats.[image]

Comment: this memory card is broken/corrupted that's why. You may try formatting it using a computer but I don't think it will work well long

Comment: How large and how old is the SD-card? Have you ever tested the SD-card by completely filling it up with data? There a forged SD-cards that claim to be much larger that they actually filling it completely such cards will fail.